# Change animation frames to only when tank moves

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've rendered a tile map and a tank on a screen in canvas:

http://www.exeneva.com/html5/movingTankExample/

However, you'll notice that the tank's animation movement (moving tracks) are regularly occurring. How would you change it so that the movement of the tank tracks occurs only when the tank is moved? Note that there is no physics at the moment.

Comment: Can you draw a version of the tank with no animation?

Comment: Yes. I'll upload a version without animation right now.

Comment: No need, I was just thinking conceptually that you could swap one out with the other when it's moving or not moving.  Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `startUp` function is calling `drawScreen` every 100 ms where the tank movement gets animated. You need to extract the animation logic from `drawScreen` into its own function, e.g. `animateMovement` and call it from your `onkeydown` handler.
Something like:

```
function animateMovement(){
    var int = setInterval(function(){
        // Tank tiles
          var tankSourceX = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth;
          var tankSourceY = Math.floor(animationFrames[frameIndex] / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight;    
          // Draw the tank
          context.drawImage(tileSheet, tankSourceX, tankSourceY, tileWidth, tileHeight, tankX, tankY, tileWidth, tileHeight);
          // Animation frames
          frameIndex += 1;
          if (frameIndex == animationFrames.length) {
            frameIndex = 0;
          }
    },100);
    setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(int);}, 1000);
}
```

Put this just before your `drawScreen` function and call it from your `document.onkeydown` handler just after you call `drawScreen`. Obviously, you will also need to remove the animation code from your `drawScreen` function:

```
function drawScreen() {
  // Tile map
  for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < mapRows; rowCtr += 1) {
    for (var colCtr = 0; colCtr < mapCols; colCtr += 1) {
      var tileId = tileMap[rowCtr][colCtr] + mapIndexOffset;
      var sourceX = Math.floor(tileId % tilesPerRow) * tileWidth;
      var sourceY = Math.floor(tileId / tilesPerRow) * tileHeight;

      context.drawImage(tileSheet, sourceX, sourceY, tileWidth, 
        tileHeight, colCtr * tileWidth, rowCtr * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    }
  }
  /*tank animation was here*/
} 
​
```

Comment: this is go over the 8 frames very quickly and the effect is not going to be very nice. You might be better off animating the movement for 500 ms

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I'm new to this stuff.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! I'll try to do something similar for the actual movement so that way it looks more streamlined as opposed to jumpy.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement a basic `state machine` that controls the atcual state of the tank.

Eg.

1. On the STOPPED state, the tank doesn't animate and it starts with this state;
2. When you press a key, you toggle the state to MOVING, so the animation function will use this flag to know when to animate your sprite;
3. When you release a key, you toggle the state back to STOPPED.

Take a look at this link (mostly the second part for the real action, the first part is more theorical): http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/the-power-of-finite-state-machines-concept-and-creation/

It's about Flash, but the concept is universal.

Comment: Kind of what I was thinking :)  +1